# How to make actionsheet button go to another page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard, uiactionsheet

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.label.text = @"Destructive Button Clicked";
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.label.text = @"Other Button 1 Clicked";
    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        self.label.text = @"Other Button 2 Clicked";
    } else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
        self.label.text = @"Cancel Button Clicked";
    }

    /**
     * OR use the following switch statement
     * Suggested by Colin =)
     */

    /*
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.label.text = @"Destructive Button Clicked";
            break;
        case 1:
            self.label.text = @"Other Button 1 Clicked";            
            break;
        case 2:
            //???????????
            self.label.text = @"Other Button 2 Clicked";   <<<<<< WHAT DO I PUT HERE???***
            //???????????
            break;
        case 3:
            self.label.text = @"Cancel Button Clicked";
            break;
     }
     */
}
```

What do I put in the places where it says `self.label` etc? I need to make one of the buttons go to another page. In other words, if I were to say "YES", "I want to continue" and I click "CONTINUE" it will take me to another storyboard.

***EDIT:*** Look at the part where it says "WHAT DO I PUT HERE", that is the place I want to know what code to type, so that I can make what I want to?

Comment: please reformat your post so we can help you

Comment: Hey man. Im sorry i am new to Stack overflow and it looked great when i posted it i dont know what i did to it lol

Comment: Your question is not clear...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to instantiate the viewcontroller and use navigation controller to go to that viewcontroller

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NewViewController *newview =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewView"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newview animated:YES];
    }
    else if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
         NewViewController1 *newview1 =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewView1"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newview1 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Now its ays "use of undeclared identifier "buttonIndex" :(

Comment: But buttonIndex is the local variable for that method...Can you post the code where you have set the **ActionSheet**?

Comment: Ok, here it is... from my .h file. Im sorry if i am doing it wrong because like i said im a noob

Comment: @SaravanaVijay lets chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29240/developers-chat